# Is there an auto highlight for runtime used code

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

Does eclipse has a feature or plugin that shows the used code branch for an execution?

I known about coverage plugins for junit test, but I would like one for normal runtime execution instead of unit tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EclEmma code coverage plug-in is not specific to JUnit executions. Measuring code coverage is an added launch mode, like Run, or Debug.

https://www.eclemma.org/userdoc/launching.html